# Sum cells by group in data frame

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, cells

I have a huge data frame that looks like this:

[image: dados]

and I want to sum the cells in column V9 according to V3; for example, I want to sum every V9 cell when V3=="Acrelândia".

Comment: `library(data.table);setDT(df)[,sum(V9),V3]`

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregate(V9~V3,df,sum);​​​​​​
```